# aws cdk synth takes wrong region

Tags: aws-cdk

In learning the AWS CDK (Python version), I am seeing a strange effect in the Default Region used by "cdk synth" command.

It looks like it changes the "CDK_DEFAULT_REGION" value somwhere, and I can't find where (and cannot change it)

This is the situation:

#### Env Vars:

```bash
(.venv) $ set | grep CDK
CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT=99999999999999
CDK_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
```

#### cdk.json

Only the first 2 lines, to prove that app.py is used

```
{
  "app": "python3 app.py",
```

#### app.py

As you see, an empty app.py, no Stacks defined.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import logging

import aws_cdk
from packages.cdk_testing.cdk_testing_stack import CdkTestingStack


if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)5s] %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
                        level=logging.NOTSET)

    app = aws_cdk.App()
    logging.info(f"{os.environ['CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT']} is account, and {os.environ['CDK_DEFAULT_REGION']} is region")

    CdkTestingStack(
        app,
        "cdk-testing",
        env=aws_cdk.Environment(
            account=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT'),
            region=os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION')
        ),
    )
    
    app.synth()
```

#### Stack file

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack
)
from constructs import Construct
from os import path


class CdkTestingStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # Empty Stack, for now
```

#### Running it in Python

```bash
(.venv) $ py app.py
2023-08-20T12:01:57 [ INFO] 99999999999999 is account, and eu-central-1 is region
```

**CDK_DEFAULT_REGION (eu-central-1) is used.**

#### Running the 'cdk synth'

```bash
(.venv) $ cdk synth
2023-08-20T12:02:47 [ INFO] 99999999999999 is account, and us-east-1 is region

This app contains no stacks
```

**But 'cdk synth' decides to use eu-east-1 !!??**

### Question

- Where is 'cdk synth' taking the region from
- How can I make sure that my own CDK_DEFAULT_REGION is used?

### Solution !!

Thanks to @fedonev for pointing this out.

Don't use the ENV Vars called **CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT** and **CDK_DEFAULT_REGION**.

They are used by AWS CDK itself.

I've fixed it by changing them to **MY_AWS_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT** and **MY_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION** and used those in the code.
And now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Where is 'cdk synth' taking the region from?

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html):  [`CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION`] are set based on the AWS profile specified using the `--profile` option, or the default AWS profile if you don't specify one.

#### How can I make sure that my own CDK_DEFAULT_REGION is used?

You can't.  The AWS CDK CLI sets the variable when you run toolkit commands like `cdk synth`, overwriting any value you have previously set.

Instead, define your own env vars:

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html): You can set env however you like, using any valid expression. For example, you might write your stack to support two additional environment variables to let you override the account and Region at synthesis time. We'll call these `CDK_DEPLOY_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEPLOY_REGION` here, but you could name them anything you like, as they are not set by the AWS CDK.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation. I have added the Stack file (python program) in which you can see that I pass those env vars to the Stack. 
But, still they are not taken and AWS-CDK uses eu-west-1 instead of the env vars.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is environment-agnostic - that is, if you don't set the `env` prop in your stacks - then the `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION` will not affect the generated CloudFormation template, as it will not contain any environment-specific values.

This means that these variables have no effect on `cdk synth` anyway. They do affect where your environment-agnostic app will be deployed to, however, as a result of `cdk deploy`.

Now, if you want your template to be environment-specific - that is, the generated CloudFormation template to specify the account/region to deploy to - then you simply need to set the `env` prop as mentioned above.

Here's an example of two environment-specific stacks from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html):

```py
env_EU = cdk.Environment(account="8373873873", region="eu-west-1")
env_USA = cdk.Environment(account="2383838383", region="us-west-2")

MyFirstStack(app, "first-stack-us", env=env_USA)
MyFirstStack(app, "first-stack-eu", env=env_EU)
```

You can use the `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT` and `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variables if you want to:

```py
MyFirstStack(
  app,
  "first-stack-eu",
  env=cdk.Environment(
    account=os.environ["CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT"],
    region=os.environ["CDK_DEFAULT_REGION"],
  ),
);
```

As you can see, you can set the environment to any value you need - if the default `CDK_DEFAULT_*` variables don't work for you, set the values to something else.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation. I have added the Stack file (python program) in which you can see that I pass those env vars to the Stack. 
But, still they are not taken and AWS-CDK uses eu-west-1 instead of the env vars.

Comment: You cannot set those specific env vars - the better approach is to pass the correct environment directly in code, without the use of any env vars (or use different ones if you must).